Terraform-vault creating vault secrets in subpath
I am new to hashicorp vault and terraform. Trying to create a secret in vault where there is already a secret with name UAT in the path kv/data/pipeline/synapse-cdo/uat/ and want to add one more secret in the subpath like kv/data/pipeline/synapse-cdo/dev/ but terrafrom deleting the UAT secret and deploying dev
resource "vault_kv_secret_v2" "deploynewsecrets" 
{  
mount = var.mountpoint name = "pipeline/synapse-cdo/dev/" 
data_json = jsonencode 
          ({ "appid" = "bnasoirhol748975" 
             "secretid" = "naihpoiepsoiporihtpeoi6547838399"
          }) 
}

vault_kv_secret_v2.deploynewsecrets: Refreshing state... [id=kv/data/pipeline/synapse-cdo/uat/]
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
\-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

# vault_kv_secret_v2.deploynewsecrets must be replaced

\-/+ resource "vault_kv_secret_v2" "deploynewsecrets" {
\~ data                = (sensitive value)
\~ id                  = "kv/data/pipeline/synapse-cdo/uat/" -\> (known after apply)
\~ metadata            = {
\- "created_time"    = "2024-11-02T06:03:23.7875518Z"
\- "custom_metadata" = "null"
\- "deletion_time"   = null
\- "destroyed"       = "false"
\- "version"         = "1"
} -\> (known after apply)
\~ name                = "pipeline/synapse-cdo/uat/" -\> "pipeline/synapse-cdo/dev/" # forces replacement
\~ path                = "kv/data/pipeline/synapse-cdo/uat/" -\> (known after apply)
\# (4 unchanged attributes hidden)

      - custom_metadata {
          - cas_required         = false -> null
          - data                 = {} -> null
          - delete_version_after = 0 -> null
          - max_versions         = 0 -> null
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.your text


You need to define both of those paths separately. It looks like you used the same terraform resource to define uat and now you're trying to use it to define dev.
You need two independent resource definitions, or, if you're trying to avoid reusing code, put it in a loop.
Also, I hope I don't have to say this, but putting secrets plain text in your codebase is an anti-pattern, and I really hope the appid and secretid you posted here aren't real.
If they are you need to now consider them compromised and reprovision them.
